# Como pegar valores do JSON que o OKhttp gerou?

Tags: java, android

Este é o meu código

```
public void loginRequestAsync() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("xxx.xxxx.xx.x.xx.xxx.x").newBuilder();
    String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("ddi", String.valueOf(ddi.getText()))
            .addFormDataPart("numero", String.valueOf(numero.getText()))
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.d("Response: ",response.body().string());

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Forneça maiores informações para ajuda!

Comment: Preciso pegar os valores que sao imprimidos no log

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor). Após incluir a biblioteca no seu projeto, basta adicioná-lo como um `Interceptor` no seu `OkHttpClient`:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .addInterceptor(logging)
  .build();
```

Ao utilizar `Level.BODY`, o corpo das requisições e respostas aparecerão no seu log. Exemplo de saída:

```
--> POST /greeting http/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: plain/text
Content-Length: 3

Hi?
--> END POST

<-- 200 OK (22ms)
Content-Type: plain/text
Content-Length: 6

Hello!
<-- END HTTP
```

Esta ferramenta deve ser utilizada com cuidado, já que ela pode expor dados sensíveis.

Comment: e se eu quiser salvar os dados do log em outra classe como posso faze?
pode me ajudar?

Comment: É possível passar um [HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/logging-interceptor/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger.html) personalizado ao instanciar o HttpLoggingInterceptor. A interface HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger define um único método [log](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/logging-interceptor/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger.html#log-java.lang.String-), que recebe as mensagens exibidas no console.